# Trying to run unit testing for a findAll() function. But getting this error " expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality "

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, nest

Error message is this.

` PASS  src/app.controller.spec.ts
FAIL  src/users/services/users.service.spec.ts
● UsersService › should  return all users

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected  - 6
+ Received  + 1

- Object {
-   "birthDate": 2010-06-07T00:00:00.000Z,
-   "email": "xs@gsuj.lk",
-   "id": 2,
-   "name": "aq1s",
- }
+ Object {}

  66 |      //const dto ={id:2, name:'aq1s',birthDate: new Date('2010-06-07'), email : "xs@gsuj.lk" };
  67 |
> 68 |     expect( await service.findAll()).toEqual({
     |                                      ^
  69 |        id:2,
  70 |        name:'aq1s',
  71 |        birthDate: new Date('2010-06-07'),

  at src/users/services/users.service.spec.ts:68:38
  at fulfilled (src/users/services/users.service.spec.ts:5:58)
```

FAIL  src/users/controllers/users.controller.spec.ts (5.09 s)
● UsersController › should findall

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

- Expected  - 6
+ Received  + 1

- Object {
-   "birthDate": 2010-06-07T00:00:00.000Z,
-   "email": "xs@gsuj.lk",
-   "id": 2,
-   "name": "aq1s",
- }
+ Object {}

  129 |     const data = await controller.findAll();
  130 |
> 131 |     expect(data).toEqual({
      |                  ^
  132 |       id: dto.id,
  133 |       name: dto.name,
  134 |       birthDate: dto.birthDate,

  at src/users/controllers/users.controller.spec.ts:131:18
  at fulfilled (src/users/controllers/users.controller.spec.ts:5:58)
```

Test Suites: 3 failed, 1 passed, 4 total
Tests:       2 failed, 9 passed, 11 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.85 s
Ran all test suites.`

Users.controller.spec.ts file is this

```
 
describe('UsersController', () => {
  let controller: UsersController;

  const mockUsersService = {
    create: jest.fn((dto) => {
      return {
        ...dto,
      };
    }),
    update: jest.fn((id, dto) => ({
      id,
      ...dto,
    })),

    delete: jest.fn((id) => ({
      id,
    })),

    findAll: jest.fn((dto) => {
      return {
        ...dto,
      };
    }),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [UsersController],
      providers: [UsersService],
    })
      .overrideProvider(UsersService)
      .useValue(mockUsersService)
      .compile();

    //get service module from user module
    controller = module.get<UsersController>(UsersController);
  });

  //check if service available
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should create', async () => {
    const dto = {
      id: 2,
      name: 'aqs',
      birthDate: new Date('2000-06-07'),
      email: 'xs@gsuj.lk',
    };

    const data = await controller.create(dto);

    expect(data).toEqual({
      id: dto.id,
      name: dto.name,
      birthDate: dto.birthDate,
      email: dto.email,
    });
    expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
 
  it('should findall', async () => {
    const dto = {
      id: 2,
      name: 'aq1s',
      birthDate: new Date('2010-06-07'),
      email: 'xs@gsuj.lk',
    };

    const data = await controller.findAll();

    expect(data).toEqual({
      id: dto.id,
      name: dto.name,
      birthDate: dto.birthDate,
      email: dto.email,
    }),
      expect(controller).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

user.service.spec.ts file is this.

```
 
describe('UsersService', () => {
  let service: UsersService;
//  let providers:UsersController;

const mockUsersRepository ={
  create:jest.fn().mockImplementation(dto =>dto),
  save:jest.fn().mockImplementation(user => Promise.resolve({id:2, ...user})),
  update:jest.fn().mockImplementation((id,user) => Promise.resolve({id:2, ...user})),
  delete:jest.fn().mockImplementation(id => Promise.resolve({id:2})),
  find:jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
 
}

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UsersService, {
        provide:getRepositoryToken(User),
        useValue:mockUsersRepository,
      },
    ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });


  it('should be create a new user record and return that', async () => {
    expect( await service.create({id:2, name:'aqs',birthDate: new Date('2000-06-07'), email : "xs@gsuj.lk" })).toEqual({
      id:2, 
      name:'aqs',
      birthDate: new Date('2000-06-07'), 
      email : "xs@gsuj.lk" ,
    });
  });
 
  
  it('should  return all users', async () => {
     //const dto ={id:2, name:'aq1s',birthDate: new Date('2010-06-07'), email : "xs@gsuj.lk" };
    
    expect( await service.findAll()).toEqual({
       id:2, 
       name:'aq1s',
       birthDate: new Date('2010-06-07'), 
       email : "xs@gsuj.lk" , 
     });
   });
});
```

users.controller file is this

```
 @Get()
  async findAll() {
    const users = await this.userService.findAll();
    if (!users) {
      return 'error while finding users';
    }
    return users;
  }
```

users.service file is this

```
  findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
     return this.userRepository.find()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by, `user.controller.spec.ts`

```
it('should find all', async () => {
  const data = await controller.findAll();

  expect(data).toEqual({}),
  expect(controller).toBeDefined();
});
```

And `user.service.spec.ts`:

```
it('should return all users', async () => {
  expect( await service.findAll()).toEqual({});
});
```